# Change color of a <tag> in html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using pagedown for posting codes. I know how to change color of specific words inside the HTML document i.e. using the sample code below

```
<script>
var text = document.getElementById("wmd-post");
var str = text.innerHTML,
    reg = /if|else|span|/ig; //g is to replace all occurances

//fixing a bit
var toStr = String(reg);
var color = (toStr.replace('\/g', '|')).substring(1);

//split it
var colors = color.split("|");

if (colors.indexOf("if") > -1) {
    str = str.replace(/if/g, '<span style="color:#069;">if</span>');
}

document.getElementById("wmd-post").innerHTML = str;
</script>
```

I also want to know how to change color for tags such as `<span>` ,`<div>`, `<p>` When i try to add them in my code above it would not work

i.e.

```
var text = document.getElementById("wmd-post");
var str = text.innerHTML,
    reg = /<span>|</div>|/ig; //g is to replace all occurances

//fixing a bit
var toStr = String(reg);
var color = (toStr.replace('\/g', '|')).substring(1);

//split it
var colors = color.split("|");

if (colors.indexOf("<span>") > -1) {
    str = str.replace(/<span>/g, '<span style="color:#069;"><span></span>');
}

document.getElementById("wmd-post").innerHTML = str;
```

What approach should i use

Comment: You should escape `/` charachter: `/<span>|<div>|<\/span>|/ig`

Comment: For that it could be solved but still the color wont change. I have added more on the question above

Comment: escape `/` charachter: `/<span>|<\/div>|/ig` in js regex and also escape html charachters in html: `'<span style="color:#069;"><span></span>'` should be: `'<span style="color:#069;">&lt;span&gt;</span>'`.

Comment: FYI `a <tag>` is known as an anchor element.

Comment: @dNitro i figured out a way with your idea. I welcome and accept any idea as an answers to the question. Or any other better approach

Comment: Any reason why you can't use plain css?

Comment: it could be a great deal if there can be a way for plain css

Comment: then you could just add this somewhere before the div: `<style> #wmd-post span { color: red; }</style>`

Comment: would that even change the words that are in the span?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to do it

```html
<div id="wmd-post">
  
  Some other words
  <p>&lt;span&gt;</p>
  <p>&lt;/span&gt;</p>
   Some more words 
  
</div>  
<script>
var text = document.getElementById("wmd-post");
var str = text.innerHTML,
    
str = str.replace(/&lt;\/span&gt;/g, '<span style="color:red">&lt;/span&gt;</span>');
str = str.replace(/&lt;span&gt;/g, '<span style="color:red">&lt;span&gt;</span>');

document.getElementById("wmd-post").innerHTML = str;
</script>
```